# Mysql Join three tables with a WHERE on the third

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables I need to join to show the following.
I can join the first two  and show all the unique nominal_acc_no's with this query

```
SELECT nominal_acc_no,coa_name FROM
(
    SELECT nominal_acc_no ,coa_name FROM acc_chart_of_accounts
    UNION
    SELECT nominal_acc_no,coa_name FROM acc_chart_of_sub_accounts
) A;
```

but I'm struggling with how to join the third and output the results shown below. I need to GROUP ON nominal_acc_no and SUM the debit & credit with a WHERE on the company_id in the acc_posting_details table.
Any and all help appreciated.

```
 Acc_chart_of_accounts           
Coa_id   nominal_acc_no 
    1           10   
    2           20        

acc_chart_of_sub_accounts
coa_sub_id    nominal_acc_no  company_id
      1             10                 1
      2             20                 1
      3             110                1



Acc_posting_details
Id         nominal_acc_no   debit    credit  company_id
1              10           25.00                1
2              10           15.00                1
3              20                    30.00       1
4              110          10.00                1
5              110           8.00                1

Result
Nominal_acc_no        debit       credit    company_id
10                    40.00         -           1
20                      -         30.00         1
110                   18.00         -           1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  acsa.nominal_acc_no,
  IFNULL(sum(apd.debit),0) AS debit,
  IFNULL(sum(apd.credit),0) AS credit,
  acsa.company_id
FROM acc_chart_of_sub_accounts AS acsa
  LEFT JOIN acc_posting_details AS apd
    ON acsa.nominal_acc_no = apd.Nominal_acc_no
GROUP BY acsa.nominal_acc_no, acsa.company_id
```

Output

```
Nominal_acc_no        debit     credit    company_id
-----------------------------------------------------
10                    40.00     0           1
20                    0         30.00       1
110                   18.00     0           1
```

EDIT : There was an alias problem i have fixed in my query. 

### SQL Fiddle Demo Here

Comment: Hi Raheel, I've tried your code, but I am only getting a blank page, no results Im afraid, also, I dont see the WHERE for the company_id.

Comment: raHeel, I've tried your query, but it returns a blank result, and there is data in the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Nominal_acc_no,SUM(debit) AS total_debit,SUM(credit) AS total_credit from   Acc_posting_details group by nominal_acc_no;
```

You can insert other where conditions before group by.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the complete structure of your tables, that is, all the columns?

Your first SELECT statement refers to a column **coa_name** within tables **acc_chart_of_accounts** and **acc_chart_of_sub_accounts**, but then you don't mention that column in description of those tables. That makes me think there might be other relevant information that is missing.

Do tables **acc_chart_of_accounts** and **acc_chart_of_sub_accounts** contain any debits or credits? If not, why do you need info from them? Based on what I understand from your question, it seems that **Acc_posting_details** has all the info you need:

> "I need to GROUP ON nominal_acc_no and SUM the debit & credit with a
>   WHERE on the company_id in the acc_posting_details table"

Does this query solve your problem?

```
 SELECT Nominal_acc_no,
        SUM(debit) AS total_debit,
        SUM(credit) AS total_credit,
        company_id
 FROM Acc_posting_details
 WHERE company_id = 1
 GROUP BY nominal_acc_no;
```

#### ADDED:

If I understand you last comment, you need to get exctly one row for every **Nominal_acc_no** that exists in **acc_chart_of_accounts**.

In that case, **Acc_posting_details** does not have all the info you need, because some nominal accounts might have no debits or credits, and so they don't exist in **Acc_posting_details**.

```
 SELECT aca.Nominal_acc_no,
        IFNULL(SUM(apd.debit),0) AS total_debit,
        IFNULL(SUM(apd.credit),0) AS total_credit,
        aca.company_id
 FROM acc_chart_of_accounts aca
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Acc_posting_details apd
              ON aca.Nominal_acc_no = apd.Nominal_acc_no
 WHERE aca.company_id = 1
 GROUP BY aca.nominal_acc_no;
```

This query will give you one row for every nominal account in **acc_chart_of_accounts**. If an account has any rows in **Acc_posting_details**, you will get their credits and debits added together. For accounts that have no records in **Acc_posting_details**, you will get 0 in the total_debit and total_credit columns.

You said that you want company_id in WHERE clasue. Alternatively, if you want a complete report over all the companies, you would remove the WHERE clause and replace the GROUP BY clause with

```
 GROUP BY aca.nominal_acc_no, aca.company_id;
```

Is this what you were looking for? Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Marjeta, thank you for your assistance, this is a little long winded, but here goes.

Comment: Hi Marjeta, thank you for your assistance, this is a little long winded, but here goes.In a multi user environment when a user creates an account, they have access to the system acc_chart_off_accounts table, now, in some cases, the nominal entries in this table may not suit the users requirements, se we allow them to create new nominal accounts, mayby like diesel costs, window cleaner, warehouse rent etc and store them in the acc_chart_of_sub_accounts table.

Comment: When they receive or pay an invoice etc, they select the nominal account to which the transaction is to be assigned, and this is posted to the posting_details table. Now, we want to show each user their chart of accounts or nominal ledger depending where you reside. The chart of accounts must show all the codes in the system table plus any that the user created along with the summed values of each nominal code if there are any entries against it.

Comment: Could you also describe the structure of Acc_posting_details? What do you get if you enter "describe Acc_posting_details;" to MySQL?

Comment: Hi Marjeta, I've had a rethink of how I am approaching this and have changed my approach. I can get the results I want from using two tables instead of three, acc_chart_of_accounts and acc_posting_details. I have gotten a bit more organised and created a fiddle here [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22ced/1/0) what I need is to be able to get all the records from acc_chart_of_accounts GROUPED on nominal_acc_no and WHERE on system_id and company_id plus any records from acc_posting_details which have entries. summed on debit & credit.

Comment: David, I've added some. Does that help?

Comment: Hi Marjeta, yes that seems to be getting there. It's returning the summed numbers ok, however, I need to be able to show all records from the acc_chart_of_accounts table. Basically, show the full chart of accounts with the relevant summed posting entries.The current query shows only the records from the left table where there is a match in the right table. I apologise for being a pain.  David

Comment: Can you show me, what this query is returning vs. what you need, with a specific example?